# Showing that a basis is an orthonormal basis with respect to given inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having difficulty showing that a basis is an orthonormal base for a vector space.

The exercise is as follows:

Let $V$ be a real or complex vector space (possibly infinite-dimensional), and let $B$ be a basis for $V$.

Where all $x$, $y$ are elements of $V$ and $B = \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ such that
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iv_i
$$

$$
y = \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_iv_i
$$

and define 
$$
x\cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\bar b_i
$$

Now the question is asking me to show that $B$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$. I really don't know how to do this.

I know exactly what an orthonormal base is, how to normalise it. I know the Gram-Schimdt process. I know the theorem that states if $V$ is a nonzero finite-dimensional Inner Product Space then $V$ has an orthonormal basis. But this could be infinite-dimensional due to the vector space given in the opening data?

What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: I know i need to show vi.vi = 1 and vi.vk = 0 for i =/= k. Is it since B is a basis for V and <.,.> is an inner product on V that it automatically implies this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if $B = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, then $\dim V = n$; in particular, $V$ is finite dimensional.

Now $v_j = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$ where $a_i = \begin{cases} 1 & i = j\\ 0 & i \neq j\end{cases}$. Note that if $v = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nb_iv_i$ then

$$v_j\cdot v = \sum_{i=1}^na_i\overline{b_i} = \overline{b_j}.$$

In particular,

$$v_j\cdot v_k = \begin{cases}
1 & j = k\\
0 & j \neq k
\end{cases}$$

so $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$.

Comment: Thanks Michael,But how do you know that ai = 0 or 1? from the given data.... ai is an arb constant? But how did you deduce its value? Same for Vj.Vk how do you know that it is = 1 or 0?

Comment: The question does not say "B is an orthonormal base, now show this" It asks me to prove it based on the given data.......Poor question? I totally understand your answer if it is stated that B is orthonormal. I dunno, I'm prob being silly and missed something

Comment: @LinearSS: I did not assume that $B$ was an orthonormal basis. I used the fact that $v_i = 1v_i = 0v_1 + \dots + 0v_{i-1} + 1v_i + 0v_{i+1} + \dots + 0v_n$.